# Add two values to a form select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, associations, simple-form

I want to include BOTH manager first name and last name in a select box below. How can I accomplish this?

Form:

```
 <%= simple_form_for @office do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :street_address %>
  <%= f.input :city %>
  <%= f.input :postal_code %>
  <%= f.input :description, as: :text %>
  <%=f.input :manager_id, collection: Manager.all, :id, :last_name, include_blank: true %>

  <%= f.submit 'Add Office' %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add something like

```
label_method: lambda { |manager| "#{manager.first_name} #{manager.last_name}" }
```

to your f.input

or you can create a new method "name" in your model, and use this one instead

```
def name
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

then

```
label_method: :name
```

Comment: thanks. any idea why this won't work in simple form to show the email? <%= f.input :manager_id, collection: Manager.all, :email, include_blank: true %>

Comment: Add label_method: in front of it!

Comment: haha I just realized that and got it working. thanks for your help